# Caching paginated data for scrolling interface and avoid client side duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pagination, redis

Basically here is the set up:

You have a number of marketplace items and you want to sort them by price. If the cache expires when someone is browsing, they will suddenly be presented potential duplicate entries. This seems like a really terrible public API experience and we are looking to avoid this problem.

Some basic philosophies I have seen include:

- Reddit's, in which they track the last id seen by the client, but they still handle duplicates.
- Will Paginate, which is a simple implementation that basically returns results based on a multiple of items you want returned and an offset
- Then there are many varied solutions that involve Redis sorted sets, etc. But these also don't really solve the problem of how to remove the duplicate entries

Does anyone have a fairly reliable way to deal with paginating sorted, dynamic lists without dupicates?

Answer (score 1):

If the items you need to paginate are sorted properly ( on unique values ) then the only thing you need to do is to select the results by that value instead of by offset.

simple SQL example

```
SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 10; /*page 1*/
```

lets say row #10 has id = 42 (and id is the primary key)

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id < 42 LIMIT 10; /* page 2*/
```

If you are using postgresql (probably mysql has same problem) this solves also the problem that using OFFSET sucks in terms of performances (OFFSET N LIMIT M needs to scan N rows!)

If sorting is not unique (eg. sorting on creation timestamp can lead to multiple items created at the same time) you are going to have the duplication problem